# SAS extracting part of text

Tags: string, sas

I have three versions of the same string:

```
 "123 aa456 aa678"
 "123 aa99 aa678"
 "45 aa28 aa234"
```

How can I extract only values between ***aa***?

I try with if `length(string)>15` then `string=substr(string,8,8)` but its only for first versions...

Answer (score 1):

You can use find + substr functions:

```
data g;
d= "123 aa456 aa678";
d_pos1=find(d,"aa");
d_pos2=find(d,"aa",d_pos1+2);
d_between_aa1=substr(d,d_pos1+2,d_pos2-d_pos1-2);
run;
```

Or use prx functions:

```
data g;
d= "123 aa456 aa678";

re= prxparse('/aa([\w\d\s\t]*)aa/');
pos = prxmatch(re, d) ;
text = prxposn(re, 1, d) ;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prxnext` function (twelveth page [here](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi30/138-30.pdf)). In your case it will look like(you need to init num of values, in my example it's 3):

```
data have;
 string =  "123 aa456 aa678";
 output;
 string =  "123 aa99 aa678";
 output;
 string =  "45 aa28 aa234";
 output; 
run;


data check_next(keep=id: string);
    array ids{3} id1-id3;
    set have;
    if _n_=1 then do;
       retain re;
       re = prxparse('/[\d]+/');
       if missing(re) then do;
          putlog 'ERROR: a regex is malformed';
          stop;
       end;
    end;
    start = 1;
    stop = length(string);
    call prxnext(re,start,stop,string,startposn,len);
    do i = 1 to 3 while(startposn > 0);
       ids{i} = input(substr(string,startposn,len),5.);
       call prxnext(re,start,stop,string,startposn,len);
    end;
run;
```

Have data set:

```
+=================+
|     string      |
+=================+
| 123 aa456 aa678 |
+-----------------+
| 123 aa99 aa678  |
+-----------------+
| 45 aa28 aa234   |
+-----------------+
```

Check_next data set:

```
+=====+=====+=====+=================+
| id1 | id2 | id3 |     string      |
+=====+=====+=====+=================+
| 123 | 456 | 678 | 123 aa456 aa678 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----------------+
| 123 |  99 | 678 | 123 aa99 aa678  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----------------+
|  45 |  28 | 234 | 45 aa28 aa234   |
+-----+-----+-----+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Example of DLMSTR INFILE statement option.

```
data test;
   infile cards dlmstr=' aa';
   input v1-v3;
   line = _infile_;
   cards;
123 aa456 aa678 
123 aa99 aa678
45 aa28 aa234
;;;;
   run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the data to be parsed is in a variable (or `_infile_`).

A loop with `SCAN` termination criteria can extract text segments (words) between delimiters -- because your string delimiter is `'aa'` the SCAN function can use the letter `'a'` as the character delimiter (because the SCAN default operation is that the empty field between adjacent delimiters (`'aa'`) is not considered an extractable piece.

Each extracted text piece can be converted to a numeric value using `INPUT` function.

If you don't know the number of items that could be scanned out, first output a 'vertical' list and transpose that.

```
data lines;
  input;
  line = _infile_;
datalines;
123 aa456 aa678
123 aa99 aa678
45 aa28 aa234
45 aa28 aa234 aa 999
45 aa this is wrong aa -234 aa 999
run;

data ids;
  set lines;

  rownum + 1;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 while (scan(line, _n_, 'a') ne '');
    id = input ( scan(line, _n_, 'a'), ??best12. );
    output;
  end;
run;

proc transpose data=ids out=want(drop=_name_) prefix=id;
  by rownum;
  var id;
run;
```

Creates output

```
rownum    id1    id2     id3    id4

   1      123    456     678      .
   2      123     99     678      .
   3       45     28     234      .
   4       45     28     234    999
   5       45      .    -234    999
```